# pandas remove rows from dataframe based on multiple conditions without for loops

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dictionary

I have a 6 column pandas data frame data I want to process and remove some rows based on certain conditions. the data frame is tab separated and looks like this:

```
RO52_HUMAN  TRIM6_HUMAN 1.83e-136   471 45.86   216
RO52_HUMAN  TRI68_HUMAN 6.46e-127   482 42.946  207
RO52_HUMAN  TRI22_HUMAN 6.49e-121   491 41.344  203
RO52_HUMAN  TRI38_HUMAN 7.15e-117   458 42.358  194
RO52_HUMAN  TRIM5_HUMAN 3.6e-114    499 40.281  201
RO52_HUMAN  TRI39_HUMAN 2.56e-111   490 39.388  193
RO52_HUMAN  TRI11_HUMAN 2.35e-109   471 43.524  205
RO52_HUMAN  TRI27_HUMAN 1.44e-108   495 37.576  186
RO52_HUMAN  TRI34_HUMAN 6.12e-105   500 43.0    215
RO52_HUMAN  TRI17_HUMAN 1.79e-87    461 37.093  171
```

the criteria for removing the rows depends on thefirst two columns only. I also have a dictionary whole keys are protein IDs like those in the first two columns and the values are also a list of other protein IDs. basically I want to remove all the rows if:

the value of the first column is in the dictionary as a key and if the value of the second column is in the values of for that key inside the dictionary. I wrote the reverse logic for this and trying to execute it some how (instead to keep the rows that do not satisfy these conditions) what I wrote is this

```
blast_out_filtered_df = blast_out_df[ -blast_out_df[0].isin(homolog_dict.keys()) | (blast_out_df[0].isin(homolog_dict.keys() & -blast_out_df[1].isin(homolog_dict[blast_out_df[0]]) ) ) ]
```

The data frame that I read into my file is called blast_out_df and the new data frame that I'm trying to create with the filtered rows is blast_out_filtered_df.
Ofcrourse running this code is giving me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Users\mstambou\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-
packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 806, in __hash__
' hashed'.format(self.__class__.__name__))
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

This is because I'm trying to index the dictionary with the value of a column at a particular row. How can I do this operation efficiently? I implemented it usint .iterrrows() method however I have over a million rows and this is just too slow. Any suggestions? Thank you.

The dictionary looks like this:

```
homolog_dict['MAPK5_MOUSE']
['MAPK5_HUMAN']
```

In this case the key is 'MAPK5_MOUSE' and the value is ['MAPK5_HUMAN'] a list of one

Comment: Can you post a sample `homolog_dict` dictionary?

Comment: >>> homolog_dict['MAPK5_MOUSE']
['MAPK5_HUMAN'] here@MaxU

Comment: it doesn't look like a dict. Can you [post it in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44398932/5741205)?

Comment: I edited the question hope that makes it clear

Answer (score 0):

was able to find a solution by doing this:

```
dct_2 = dict(RO52_HUMAN=['TRI68_HUMAN', 'TRI67_HUMAN'])

blast_out_df[map(isnt_in, zip(blast_out_df[1], blast_out_df[0].map(dct_2)))]
```

and by defining my own function:

```
def isnt_in(lst_item):     
    if str(lst_item[1])== 'nan':
        return True
    return lst_item[0] not in lst_item[1]
```

The map function on it's own won't cut since the values for my dictionary are lists. Also I had to define my own function because map will return np.nan values if I cant find the keys to that dictionary, the function will return True in these cases for the purpose of this task.